# how to change an index in a StringBuilder based on what the user enters

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I want to change an index on a `StringBuilder` based on a string the user enters for example i made an array but i have to change it into a string so i used `StringBuilder` to do so. Now i created another string that will have the user input and then replace the index with what the user entered. Here is what i have:

```
    Arrays inventory = new Arrays();
    String[] words = inventory.getWords();
    String[] category = inventory.getCategory();
    String board = "";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : words) {
        builder.append(s+"\n");
    }
```

This is another part of the code. The part i want it to change the index but i get an error saying that the method `setCharAt` is undefined for the string type. i also tried other methods like `replace()` but get the same error. I have to use strings for this:

```
 String word1 = builder.substring(0, 7);
     board.equals(word1);
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter a letter to guess the word");
     String input = in.nextLine();
     char aChar = builder.charAt(0);
     if (input.equals(aChar)){
         board.setCharAt(0, input);
         System.out.println(board);
     }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Note that `input.equals(aChar)` will **never** be true

Comment: Strings are immutable so there is no `setCharAt` method. To do this you need to use a StringBuilder.

Comment: my question is how to change the index of the string depending on what the user enters. lets say a word is "huston" but each letter would be replaced by * and if the user enters u the asteriscs that are the same as a u will be replaced

Comment: I attempted to answer your question but as stated in the answer I'm not sure I understand your problem. Like @RC stated above there are other problems in the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a StringBuilder with `*`'s for each letter:

```
  String theWord = "enter";
  StringBuilder board = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++) {
     board.append("*");
  }
```

Gather users input (not included for brevity)

```
  char usersInput = 'e';  // For example
```

Find characters that match ones in the original word and replace * in StringBuilder.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++) {
     if (theWord.charAt(i) == usersInput) {
        board.setCharAt(i, usersInput);
     }
  }
  System.out.println(board.toString());
```

This would produce `"e**e*"`

Comment: ok let me explain better i have an arraylist and then i have to conver it into a  string so is used stringbuilder and did the following

Comment: `Arrays inventory = new Arrays();
String[] words = inventory.getWords();
String[] category = inventory.getCategory();`

Comment: then i just created the stringbuilder `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for(String s : words) {
   builder.append(s+"\n");`
  }

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < words[0].length(); i++){
     board+= "*";
    }
    System.out.println(board);` now this if statement just prints a word from the array and prints it with * and i want to change every letter that is found in the word so if the user enter an i every i will * will be replaced to an i depending on the index how do i do that

Comment: Hope my revised answer addresses the problem you were having. Good luck.